# Call object function when pushbbotton clicked

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm new to Qt. I have a problem connect Qt widget with C++ object

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <DBMS.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DBMS dbms;
    
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QInputDialog"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&create_DB_Frm);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&select_DB_Frm);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&delete_DB_Frm);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_CreateNewDatabase_clicked()
{
    QInputDialog inputDialog;
    QString dbName = inputDialog.getText(this, "Database Name", "Provide name for your database");
    //Right here i want to call dbms objec, which i define in main.cpp and call it function
//like : dbms.addDatabase(dbNames);
}
```

DBMS.cpp

```
#include <DBMS.h>

DBMS::DBMS()
{

}

void DBMS::addName(QString strName)
{
    str.push_back(strName);
}

DBMS::~DBMS()
{

}
```

DBMS.h

```
#ifndef DBMS_H
#define DBMS_H
#include <QString>
#include <vector>

class DBMS
{
public :
    DBMS();
    void addName(QString);
    ~DBMS();
private:
    std::vector <QString> str;
};



#endif // DBMS_H
```

My question is: How can I call function ```addDatabase(Qstring )`` from DBMS.cpp when I click the CreateNewDatabase button
(CreateNewDatabase button was create in Qt designer)

I think it gotta be involve with signal and slot but I've been searching around online and no where I can find a clear answer for this

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `std::vector <QString>`, instead of a [`QStringList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html)?

Comment: Your DBMS has a function `DBMS::addName()` , which should be defined as a slot to call with _signal/slot_ model ... for that also your DBMS should have the  _Q_OBJECT macro_ , and note that in order to `QObject::connect()` signals to slots the DBMS object should be known inside your `mainwindow` .. you could create the DBMS object inside `mainwidow` ..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something someone can tell you the answer for, you'll need to understand how the signal / slot mechanism works in Qt.

For example your class DBMS has to derive from QObject.

Search the Index section of Qt Assistant for this term: Q_OBJECT

Then read some of the links in this section:
See also Meta-Object System, Signals and Slots, and Qt's Property System.